# CSS Responsive White Space Trouble

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm designing a website with media queries. I started width

```
@media screen and (min-width : 320px) and (max-width : 479px)
```

screen codes.

But there is a problem when I test it with my phone. There is a white space right side.

My web site is

http://zinzinzibidi.com/TurkAntivirusResponsive/Anasayfa

And you can test it here

http://www.responsinator.com/?url=zinzinzibidi.com%2FTurkAntivirusResponsive%2FAnasayfa

or here

http://www.browserstack.com/responsive

320x480 resolution

Here my CSS codes

http://zinzinzibidi.com/Areas/TurkAntivirusResponsive/Content/css/style.css

Where did I do wrong?

Comment: For those of us who cannot or choose not to load unknown third party websites, could you please [edit] your question to include some screenshots of what the unexpected output looks like on your computer?

Answer (score 2):

Try to change:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 479px) and (min-width: 320px){
  #header-main {
    //early 320px , it is wrong value
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
  }
}
```

Comment: #header-container has #header-container {
        width: 300px;
        padding: 0 10px;
        height: 800px;
        position: relative;
        margin: auto;
    } you looking wrong codes...

Comment: no. that doesn't change. early is also true. i am using padding: 0 10px; on the others. everything is ok.

i used overflow-x: hidden instead. thanks by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Then you had create breakpoint like that @media screen and (min-width : 320px) and (max-width : 479px) . Can you replace with @media screen and (min-width : 320px) and (max-width : 480px) for a while and see

Comment: I didn't see change on code. I told you max-width: 479px replace to max-width: 480px on style.css