# Interesting CSS Responsive Width Trouble

Tags: css, html, responsive-design, width, media-queries

I'm designing a web site

http://zinzinzibidi.com/TurkAntivirusResponsive/Anasayfa

It has a white space problem at right side.

http://www.responsinator.com/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fzinzinzibidi.com%2FTurkAntivirusResponsive%2FAnasayfa

You can see there is an extra "scroll X" area at 320px width;

My CSS file: http://zinzinzibidi.com/Areas/TurkAntivirusResponsive/Content/css/style.css

I can't see any wrong code at my CSS.

How can I fix it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS Responsive White Space Trouble](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20768849/css-responsive-white-space-trouble)

Answer (score 0):

I was check you site, extra "scroll x" area is in all format
try to avoid width and fixed width
use width=100% instead
Ok, you put

```
 html {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

its hide scroll but not solve your problem
1st you menu

```
.nav-mobile {
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 320px; <-- delete or put 100%
}
```

next line

```
.nav-mobile-button {
border-bottom: 1px dotted #777777;
cursor: pointer;
font-weight: bold;
height: 60px;
line-height: 60px;
margin: auto;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out 0s;
width: 320px; <-- delete or put 100%
```

}

That's just some of your lines to manage experiment whit your css
you have some padding that force some div sections out of screen